# Display img with class materialbox in materialize css with angular 2+

Tags: angular, materialize

Currently I have a slider inside a modal that displays images as a gallery, the slider works correctly, I expect the image to be expanded when clicked, this also works fine but when I zoom out the image is replaced by a gray background.

```
<div class="slider" materialize="slider">
   <ul class="slides">
     <li *ngFor="let url of imageURLs">
        <img materialize="materialbox"
         class="materialboxed media-object"
         [src]="url">
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I saw the exact same issue in [here](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2597) but instead of being the carousel my issue is within the slider. I saw many people saying the following code solved it, but idk how to set this up in angular 4. Any help is very appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
});
```

Comment: Could you show an example of this problem in a webpage or upload your code on jsfiddle or ...

Comment: @bahmanparsamanesh I tried uploading to plunker but I'm having problems with the initial setup and havn't found a materialize plunker working with angular...I'll try uploagind to github in a new project